# Monitor is flickering sometimes

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, power

I have two monitors from BenQ BL2706HT. I bought them in September 2018.

From time to time, the monitors do flicker. One of them flickers very heavy, so that I cannot user him until the flickering stops. After 1-5 hours they stop flickering. They flicker sometimes one day a week, sometimes one day a month.

I checked different cables (DVI, HMDI, D-SUB), plugged them on different PC's and Laptops with different OS and used different power plugs from my flat. If they flickered, then they flickered on all scenarios that I described above.

BENQ support claimes that this has to do with the my power plug of the house we life in (Berlin, apartment building, 12 flats, build in 1938). But sometimes only one of them is flickering and the left on is always flickering way heavier then the right one.

I also tried to capture the flickering with my mobile device:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PqVlcsUTrzg&feature=youtu.be

Unfortunately, the flickering is not visible. My mobile camera cannot see it for some reason. However one can see remains of the terminal that I had open before on 00:18. Also when the terminal was fullscreen at the start, the monitor did not flicker. I can reproduce this at the moment, every time I put terminal on fullscreen it does not flicker, when I minimize it or open a browser/image it will flicker again.

I also changed the power supply cable for my PC, but it did not help.

Any ideas how I can solve this issue? BENQ supports said they can't do anything about it if its just a temporary issue, they have to reproduce it when I send it to them.

If its really the power supply of my house, what kind of monitor may I buy that will not flicker? Is the Hz number important? I also wanted a monitor with low-blue-light. Is this maybe also a problem?

Comment: YouTube says "This video is not available"

Comment: @montonero whoups thanks for noting. I had the wrong setting. Now it should be visible

Comment: Unfortunately video is not very helpful. You could try to disable picture stabilization in your mobile device's camera.